# Force Git to display help manpages in Chrome browser

Tags: git

I am using Git through the PowerShell extension PoshGit, and I have Notepad++ associated as the default program for opening HTML files. This is because I most often than not don't want to view an HTML file when I double click it, but see the contents.

When I run `git help <git-command>` in PowerShell, Git opens the help file in NotePad++, obviously because Notepad++ is the default app associated for HTML files.

Is there any way that I can change the command line that `git help <git-command>` uses, or configure Git to use a non-default app to open the HTML help files?

Comment: The help page is a text file https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/blob/master/test/git-help.txt

Comment: @Biswapriyo Only the help file for `git-help` straight. The help files displayed by default for git commands, e.g. `git-help commit`, i.e. the git man pages, are HTML.

Comment: So what is it that you're running? `git help` or `git-help`? Because the latter would be non standard and likely some wrapper from PoshGit. In which case you might just modify PoshGit to use a program of your choosing for `git-help`.

Comment: @Seth I apologize for my typo. I only ever run `git help`, and have corrected the error in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two configuration values that allow you to control how help is displayed by git.

1. `help.format` controls how help is generally displayed. The valid options are `man` (as in manpage), `info` and `web`. If you're seeing the HTML version of the help the default for PowerShell is probably `web`, which is what you want.
2. `web.browser` controls the browser that opens the web-help. Set it to `chrome`. If this doesn't work, explicitly set `browser.chrome.path` to the fullpath of your Chrome executable.